# How are these Brazilian Portuguese names pronounced in English?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

How are these Brazilian (Portuguese) names pronounced in (U.S.) English?

- João Gilberto
- Astrud Gilberto
- Bebel Gilberto
- Vinicius de Moraes
- Antonio Carlos Jobim
- Vivo Sonhando

Comment: In English, names are usually pronounced as close to their original language as possible. So, there is probably no one answer to this, depending on who's speaking.

Comment: Then how are they pronounced in Portuguese?

Comment: @Simchona: 'as close to...as possible' makes it sound like foreign language speakers actually come pretty close. In general, if a local language person -reads- something foreign, even when educated, will tend to read the foreign words as though they are the written for the local language, of course butchering it as the original language. So the answer is most commonly 'literally', or in English 'Vee voh son hand oh' or 'joe ow jill bear toh'.

Comment: @jftuga Ask someone who knows Portuguese.

Comment: @Mitch: I won't deny that names (including the ones I say) get butchered, but at least in general I don't try to say them without knowing something of how they sound.

Comment: @simchona: the question was about US English in general, not about AmE speakers who are generally educated, or ... OK answer coming then!

Comment: Hmm. I attended a conference where the speaker's name was João. He introduced himself this way: "My name is [Zhon]; but you can call me [Zhow]; it's OK..."

Comment: @cindi I reopened it. It was ridiculous. Authoritative sources for pronunciations of proper names are hard but not impossible to find.

Comment: It's worth noting that the name Astrud is of Northern European origin; the singer was born Astrud Weinert to a German father. So what you're asking for here is how an English speaker would pronounce a German name as if it were Portuguese!

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology).

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it appropriate to use the original pronunciation of a foreign word versus the English pronunciation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-original-pronunciation-of-a-foreign-word-versu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rare for an native (first language) American English speaker to have any idea how the orthography for Brazilian names to work, so they will pronounce them with the rules of American orthography:

- João Gilberto: dzhoh ow dzhill bear tow
- Astrud Gilberto: ass truhd dzhill bear tow
- Bebel Gilberto: bee buhl dzhill bear tow
- Vinicius de Moraes: vin ee shee us duh muh ray ess
- Antonio Carlos Jobim: an tow nyo car lohss dzhow beem
- Vivo Sonhando: vee voh sun han doh

(yes, the transcription is in 'sound it out' English orthography; IPA would take forever)

It is obviously not expected that an AmE speaker would be able to pronounce the nasal, but even though they could pronounce the 'ny' in Brazilian 'nh' or the initial 'g' has glottal aspirate 'h', Portuguuese (Brazilian at that) orthography is pretty rare, and so could not be expected to be known at all. (Spanish is popular enough for AmE speakers, and even there the orthography is not so well known).

As to news- or sportscasters, often they are given a close enough approximation so that the names aren't agonizingly butchered.

Comment: Quick comment about newscasters - if you think american newscasters butcher Brazilian names you have no idea of how much Brazilian newscasters butcher names from America and other countries.

Comment: Vinicius de Moraes is closer to "vin ee **see** us duh muh ray ess"

Comment: @Null: My answers were somewhat both my expectation of other AmE speakers and my own uneducated pronunciation. If I were trying to pronounce them 'correctly' I would use some quasi-Spanish 'Hill bear toe' which I take is wrong. But that would also what most AmE speakers would be attuned to (most having little to no experience with Portuguese).

Comment: by "rules of American orthography" what you mean is "letter-to-sound rules of the English spelling system", right? Also, you don't distinguish the pronunciation strategies of people who might know what they're talking about with people who have never seen the words before... Don't you think that these words would be most likely to be spoken by someone who has a clue what they mean, and therefore how they might be pronounced?

Comment: @nohat: I'm not sure I understand what seem to be your objections 1) re orthography, yes, I meant that (not sure what the alternatives are), 2) no I don't distinguish those because the OP didn't. If an AmE speaker had a clue then they'd pronounce them better. My answer is basically saying that I expect most AmE speakers to not have a clue here.

Comment: @Mitch I'm sorry I was a little testy, it was not meant to be directed at you; it was more based on the meta discussion of this question. I just meant to say that I think that what you wrote is how an American English speaker might guess how to pronounce those, it's not how they would pronounce them if they heard someone say them in Portuguese first, and the latter case is worth more consideration than you gave it.

Comment: @nohat: The "letter-to-sound rules of the English spelling system" of course vary by acccent and dialect.

Comment: Your use of "dz" for "dzh" is a little off, in my opinion.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: yes, I agree. edited.

Comment: ***Please please please please*** use IPA.  For example, *João* is /ʒuˈɐ̃w̃/ with nasal dipthong or even /ʒw̃ɐ̃w̃/ with a nasal triphthong, which is somewhat peculiar in general but common in Portuguese. I don’t care whether it takes forever: if you don’t, it will be just so much nonsense. If you don’t know Portuguese, then I’ll do it.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology).

Comment: @tchrist: I understand and welcome the use of IPA for pronunciation. But the point of my question and answer is not correct BPr pronunciation, but expected -American- pronunciation which is most likely not aware of BPr pronunciation -or- orthography rules. Then there's the issue of knowing IPA...I don't know it well, and my choices will be horribly wrong -for the American pronunciation that I know well-. I am not doing the native BPr pronunciation (that's not what the OP asked for).

Comment: Very well.  I’ll try to do all three.

Comment: @tchrist: 3? Ocatvio and nohat did the BPr. Presumably you're going to try the AmE version in IPA. What's the third?

Comment: Well, yes mostly the English IPA phonetics because I despise the fako spello approach as being meaningless and confusing, but also trying for actual phonetics for the Portuguese. Unlike a narrow [phonetic] transcription, a broad /phonemic/ transcription makes sense only to someone extremely well-acquainted with the target language’s phonology, because otherwise you’ll get the allophones wrong.  For example, if you map ‹r› to /r/, an English-speaker will actually  say [ɹ], but a Portuguese speaker never will.  They’ll say any of [r], [ɾ], [ʁ], or [h] depending on a bunch of other things.

Answer (score 10):

@nohat's transcription is pretty close. But being a Brazilian Portuguese speaker myself, I can assure you that the native pronunciation is more like:

- Gilberto /ʒilˈbɛrtʊ/
- João - /ʒuˈãʊ/
- Astrud - /asˈtrudʒi/
- Bebel - /be'bɛl/
- Vinicius de Moraes /viˈnisjus dʒi moˈrajs/
- Jobim - /ʒoˈbĩ/
- Vivo Sonhando /ˈvivu so'ɲãdʊ/

Added after the OP's edit:

- Toquinho - /to'kiɲʊ/
- Manhã de Carnaval - /ma'ɲã dʒi karna'vaw/

Comment: Thanks, these are indeed to the best of my knowledge, how they are pronounced in Brazilian Portuguese, and my answer is approximately how they are pronounced by American English speakers with more than a passing knowledge of the subjects.

Comment: This is much better.

Comment: hey, Otávio! you're the man, dude! great to see a fella also spending time at StackExchange. :D

Answer (score 9):

With these names, as with most foreign words in general, it will very depending on the speaker and how much they know about the words' pronunciation in their original language.  But as a general rule, a sufficiently educated speaker will pronounce foreign names using **the closest approximation to their original pronunciation that's possible using sounds available in English**.

*João*, for instance, is generally pronounced in Portuguese as /ʒuˈɐ̃w̃/ (at least in Iberian Portuguese; I don't know how different it is in Brazilian Portuguese) but this last diphthong doesn't occur in English, so it would become something like /ʒuˈaʊ/ ("zhoo-ow").

However, Portuguese tends to suffer on the way a bit more than most languages, since it looks (to English-speaking eyes) very similar to Spanish, whose pronunciation is completely different but (at least in the US) much better-known.  So *João* may often end up butchered as /həʊˈaʊ/ ("hoe-ow").

With this in mind, the names you give would usually end up in English as something like:

- João: somewhere between "zhwow", "zhoo-*ow*" and "hoe-*ow*";
- Gilberto: somewhere among "heel-*bare*-toe", "zheel-*bare*-toe", "geel-*bare*-toe"; or possibly "gill-*bert*-oh".
- Astrud: between "*ass*-trood" and "*ah*-struth" (with the vowel of "hood" in the second syllable);
- Bebel: between "*beh*-bel" and "*bay*-bel"
- Vinicius: "vee-*nee*-see-ous" (with the "ee" vowels fairly short), or possibly with a soft "th" for the *c*;
- de Moraes: between "deh mo-*rice*" and "day muh-*rye*-ess";
- Antonio Carlos: both of these, as well-known names in English, tend to get pretty completely Anglicised;
- Jobim: between "zho-*veem*" and "hoe-beem";
- Vivo: "*vee*-voe" and "*vee*-vuh";
- Sonhando: between "suhn-*yahn*-duh" and "sohn-*yan*-doh".

I'm very aware these aren't the correct pronunciations that the artists themselves would use; I don't know nearly enough about Portuguese pronunciation to answer that.  But this is (I'm pretty confident in asserting) how they'll generally be rendered by moderately well-educated U.S. English-speakers.

Answer (score 8):

English speakers familiar with the bossa nova canon will know how to pronounce these names:

- Gilberto /ʒɪlˈbɛrtuː/ or /ʒɪlˈbɛrtoʊ/
- João - /ʒoʊˈaʊ/ or /dʒoʊˈaʊ/
- Astrud - /æsˈtruːd/
- Bebel - /ˈbɛbəl/
- Vinicius de Moraes /viːˈniːsiːəs deɪ moʊˈrɑɪs/
- Jobim - /ʒoʊˈbiːm/ or /dʒoʊˈbiːm/
- Vivo Sonhando /ˈviːvoʊ soʊnˈjɑnduː/ or /soʊnˈjɑndoʊ/

Where there are two pronunciations, the first pronunciation is "closer" to Portuguese.

As a side note to those who are wondering who and what all these names are: the first five are all people who have Wikipedia entries and are extremely famous musicians, known world-wide as being the central figures of the bossa nova musical movement (except maybe Bebel, but she's João's daughter). The main airport in Rio de Janeiro is even named after Jobim! The song "Vivo Sonhando" is one of the most famous songs (in the top 15, at least) of the bossa nova canon. There are nearly a hundred recordings of the song for sale at the iTunes Store, and it is listed on Jobim's article under "notable compositions".

Comment: This is even better.  Thanks.  But <nh> in Portuguese is the same as <ñ> in Spanish.  Both are /ɲ/, you know. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology).

Comment: Not being a phoneme of English, /ɲ/ becomes /nj/ in English words.

Comment: ♦ yes, I know. I was confused about whether you were was attempting a English or a Brazilian version.

Comment: I thought about my previous statement and I realized it's not quite right. Spanish and Portuguese  /ɲ/ sometimes becomes /nj/ in English words (as in *canyon* and *caipirinha*) and sometimes it becomes just plain /n/ (as in *Montana* and *piranha*). In any case, yes, I was attempting English pronunciations here, as the original questioner asked for.

Comment: I don’t why you have a schwa in /moʊˈrɑɪəs/.  I’d in English say [mɵˈɹaɪs], myself. Also, I’d reduce "Astrud" to [əsˈtɹuːd] in English. I think we aren’t doing the same sort of transcription, because I can’t think of an [æ] in unstressed position in my own speech.

Comment: Good point about the schwa in Moraes. It is corrected now. As for unstressed /æ/, what about *Algeria*, *asbestos*, and *magnetic*? Those all have unstressed /æ/ for me, in the same way I pronounce Astrud.

Comment: You’re right about *Algeria* and such. I just wouldn’t think to switch to an alien phoneme.  It’s like how the Brits pronounce *taco* as `[ˈtʰækoʊ]` and *macho* as `[ˈmætʃoʊ]`, whereas Americans invariably pronounce them as `[ˈtʰakoʊ]` and `[ˈmatʃoʊ]`, respectively. Why a people that says `[daːns]` not `[dæns]` and `[ɹaːzbɹi]` not `[ɹæzbeɹi]` has to go screwing up all the perfectly fine `/a/` vowels in imports, I shall never ever ever understand.

Comment: For a word that’s rather like *Astrud* in all but its last two sounds, I say *astray* as `[əsˈtʃɹeɪ]` in English, with a schwa ə not an æ.  But like you I do say *Algiers* as `[ælˈdʒiːɹz]`. I do not know why one but not the other.  Weird.

Answer (score 4):

This is not meant to replace anybody else’s answer, just supplement them. Parlty this is because I’d like to have both the English and the Portuguese (well, and/or Brazilian) versions in the same place. But it’s also because I’m going to give fairly narrow phonetic transcriptions, which are very important, especially for the Portuguese since few English speakers have any clue about Portuguese phonology.

For the English, I just do whatever  my mouth would do for these words in English using only native English phonemes picking whichever is closest to the original in Portuguese. I ***don’t*** try to read the letters as though they were English letters, which is the fatal flaw that English announcers ignorant of Portuguese so often do. Don’t do that. Just remaps the sounds, not the letters. And don’t pronounce it as though it were Spanish, either!

I then also provide a few  different phonetic transcriptions for the Portuguese, also fairly narrow. This should help you get an idea of some of the range of actual variation there can be in speakers depending on region, education, social context, and phrasal context. There are more possibilities than those I’ve shown here.

- **João Gilberto** would most likely be `[ʒəˈaʊ ʒɪɫˈbeɹtou]` in English. There could also be a bit of rounding there, so `[ʒʊ̈ˈaʊ]` or `[ʒuˈaʊ]`. Portuguese versions include  `[ʒuˈɐ̃ũ   ʒɨlˈbɛɾt̪u]` or `[ʒʊˈɐ̃ũ   ʒiwˈbɛʁt̪o]`.  Other versions of ‹r› are certainly possible,  including a full [r] on both sides of the Atlantic, or just in Brazil also [x], [h], or even [ʀ].
- **Astrud** would be something like `[əsˈtʃɹuːd]` in English.   It isn’t really a Portuguese name, but if you make your mouth behave in a more Portuguese way, it could be `[ɐʃˈt̪ɾuð]` or `[ɐsˈt̪ɾud̪]`. Those should be a dental ‹t› and ‹d› in Portuguese just like in Italian or Spanish,  not the alveolar ones we use in English or German. The lenition of `[d̪]` to `[ð]` occurs in central and northern Portugal, as well as in all of Spain. It doesn’t happen in Brazil.
- **Bebel** has the same problem of not being a common Portuguese name.  I’d say `[bɨˈbɛɫ]` or `[bəˈbɛɫ]` in English. Portuguese could have `[bəˈbɛl]` or in some speakers `[bɨˈbɛw]`, as though it’s spelt ‹bébéu›.
- **Vinicius    de    Moraes** is another weird one because of the foreignness of the first word. They might try a four-syllable Latin-style pronunciation. I might try `[vɨˈniːsi.ɵs deɪ mɵˈɹaɪs]` or  `[vəˈniːsi.əs deɪ məˈɹaːɪs]` in English.
  In Portuguese, it could be `[vĩˈnisjʊʃ d̪ɯ̟  muˈɾajʃ]` or `[vɨˈnisjus d̪ɨ mʊˈɾajs]`.
- **Antônio       Carlos   Jobim** in English would simply be `[ɒnˈtʰoʊni.oʊ ˈkaɹloʊs ʒoʊˈbiːm]` for me.  Possible Portuguese versions include `[ɐ̃ˈt̪ɔni.u      ˈkaɾluʒ‿ʒuˈbĩ]` and `[ɐ̃ˈt̪oni.ʊ ˈkaʁlʊs ʒʊˈbĩ]`. In Portugal it would be *António* with an "open o" spelt ‹ó› and said [ɔ], but in Brazil it’s *Antônio* with a “closed o” spelt ‹ô› and said [o]. A Portuguese person would still pronounce it with an open-o there, no matter how the Brazilians spell it. :)
- **Vivo Sonhando** is a really funny “name”: it literally means *I live dreaming*. In English, I’d likely say `[ˈviːvoʊ soʊnˈjandoʊ]`.  Portuguese pronunciations would probably be more like `[ˈvivu suˈɲɐ̃d̪u]` or `[ˈvivʊ sʊˈɲɐ̃d̪ʊ]`.

People aren’t used to hearing the Portuguese palatalized syllable-final ‹s› in English,  especially in the States, so I probably wouldn’t do that in English as I would in Portuguese.  Interestingly, the BBC does do so, however, when pronouncing Portuguese names in English, trying to come as close to the Coimbra pronunciation as allowed for by English phonology.

I’ve chosen a **[phonetic]** transcription rather than a broad **/phonemic/** one, because a native speaker of English unacquainted with Portuguese phonology would have no idea which allophones are possible, or likely, given a Portuguese phoneme. It takes some getting used to, and Spanish is no help here.

I find the IPA a lot easier to read in the literal font here. Otherwise my web browser screws up the narrow-transcription diacritics I’ve used.

---

**Bibiliography**

- [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)
- [IPA for English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_chart_for_English_dialects)
- [IPA for Portuguese and Galician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aIPA_for_Portuguese_and_Galician)
- Portuguese phonology, in [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology) and in [Portuguese](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%EDngua_portuguesa). Oddly, the English version is more detailed. Unsurprisingly, they do not use the same conventions, however. For example, the English version gives *santo* as the narrow `[sɐ̃ⁿtʊ]`, whereas the Portuguese version gives *entro* as the broad `/ˈɐ̃tɾu/`.

Correction welcome as always.

Comment: Wow, this is indeed a very good answer! +1.