# Foreign name usage in conversation

Tags: pronunciation

I’m English and confused.  Is jalapeno spoken with the sound ‘jal’ or ‘hal’? ‘Hal’ is how Spanish people pronounce it, but I’m English.  If the answer’s ‘hal’, do I say I’m going to ‘Paree’ instead of Paris? Do we pronounce differently based on a Person’s name, Country/City or food?

Comment: I reckon [When is it appropriate to use the original pronunciation of a foreign word versus the English pronunciation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-original-pronunciation-of-a-foreign-word-versu) answers this question.

Comment: ‘Jalapeño’ does have an established English pronunciation: [ˌhɑləˈpeɪnjoʊ] _ha-luh-pain-yo_. Pronouncing it with a [ʤ] sound would not be an ‘English’ pronunciation, but a spelling pronunciation, akin to pronouncing Worcestershire sauce as [ˈwɒ(ɹ)ˌsɛstə(ɹ)ˌʃaɪə(ɹ)] _war-sester-shai-er_ sauce, rather than [ˈwʊstə(ɹ)ʃə(ɹ)] _wooster-sher_ sauce.

Comment: The pronunciation of every single word is figured out individually for that one word. Not based on whether it's a country or a dish. Some say tomato, others say tomato, and then over the course of time one happens to prevail. Or not. And this is actually true of all words, not just the borrowed ones.