# Pronunciation of foreign words by foreign speakers

Tags: pronunciation, french

I've used English for a long time and it isn't immediately obvious to others that I'm native French. Whenever I say a French word or place name in English I wonder whether I should pronounce it like English or French speakers would. (Of course I always use English pronunciation for common place names like Paris.) Using French pronunciation can sound pretentious, but English pronunciation can too, especially if part of the audience speaks French and knows that I am native French.

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-original-pronunciation-of-a-foreign-word-versu) is similar. My question focuses on native French speakers that speak in English to an audience of both English and French natives. Which pronunciation draws less attention?

Comment: In a situation like that, suit yourself. Whatever **you** think is appropriate is the way to speak; and people vary a great deal, as you no doubt realize, in how they approach this issue. Since you realize you may not suit everyone's taste, you might as well suit at least your own.

Comment: @John: I can't recall the *exact* context, but I recently noticed a radio presenter (non-native speaker) using the "Anglicised"  pronunciation of one of her fellow countrymen's surnames when referring to the man in an initial introductory spiel (addressed to the audience), then switching to the "native" pronunciation when she actually welcomed the interviewee (by using his name addressed to *him*). I specifically remember thinking *"That sounds simultaneously 'odd' and 'natural'!"*.

Comment: My rule is that I don't translate/pronounce a person's name in other that the way they have chosen but this is an etiquette issue

Comment: @Third News Try this list of Polish surnames and tell me how you might pronounce them then. http://genealogy.familyeducation.com/browse/origin/polish

Comment: This is a hard problem. I'm sure _somebody_ will find fault with whatever you do. Just 'be consistent' is impossible in the situation provided.

Comment: @ThirdNews Except that that is not really possible. When speaking English, a Spanish name like *Ricardo* will never sound like it is pronounced Spanish. In English it will be `[ɻʷəˈkʰɑɹdoʊ̯]` while in Spanish it will be `[riˈkäɾð̪̞o̞]`, and there is virtually no overlap in actual phones there at all between the two versions. Your mouth can’t switch mid-phrase to the other articulation set for just one word. You could no more switch to saying *Richard* in the middle of a Spanish sentence. The sounds are just not there.

Comment: @tchrist I do so all the time but there is a inherent benefit from speaking languages maternally that others do not grasp.  Humorously, as a child this synctabasis was intellectually unconscious but for recognizing that I would not be otherwise (clearly) understood  -the purpose off all language

Comment: @tchrist There is an abundant literature on code-switching which demonstrates without a doubt that it is certainly possible, at least for bilingual speakers, and in places where such speakers are common (Spanish/English bilinguals in parts of the US or French/English bilinguals in parts of Canada) such switching is the norm.  A lot depends on your audience. And for bilingual speakers, adopting a non-native pronunciation for a proper names especially is quite difficult.

Comment: @ThirdNews Exactly, if a guy is introduced to you as Jesús you are not going to start calling him Jesus, in the same way Spanish people never call me Franco.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend the following strategy:

- For place names that actually have an anglicised name, always use that ("Paris", "Normandy", "Brittany", "Brussels", "The Dordogne");
- For place names that are well-known in England, if your pronunciation of English generally is fairly proficient, then try to "anglicise" your pronunciation a little, e.g. by pronouncing "Marseille(s)" and "Lourdes" without a French 'r' and moving the vowels a little closer to their English counterparts;
- For place names with alternative pronunciations in French where English speakers tend towards one of the pronunciations, try to notice which one tends to be used in English and use that, even if it's not the pronunciation used by inhabitants of that town. So for example, English speakers tens to be used to pronouncing "Chamonix" without the final [ks], or to pronouncing "Metz" with its "German" pronunciation [mEts] (whereas actual inhabitants of the town don't usually pronounce the 't').
- Subtly, consider adopting "mispronounced" versions of names that are commonly used by English speakers. For example, English speakers tend to pronounce "Bayeux" with [be-] rather than [ba-] at the start and commonly omit the final [s] of "Saint-Saëns" (either as the town or the composer) when they come across it-- not because these towns really have "English" names as such, just that English speakers commonly mispronounce them when attempting to call them by their "French" name;
- For lesser known place names, where English speakers aren't used to hearing the name pronounced either with an "English" or "French" accent, I would suggest just adopting the French pronunciation without trying to give it an "English accent".

Comment: +1 This is by far the most rational answer so far, as it recognizes the range of possible variation that might arise.

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker who has reasonable command of French and especially enjoys the sound of it, I tend to keep the proper-noun pronunciations consistent with the language I am speaking.

Take for example the French surname *Jacques*, which is reasonably widespread in Britain (among people of Huguenot and Walloon descent). In Britain it is mostly pronounced JAKES, which is understandable and fits with the sounds of an English sentence.

Using the French pronunciation of *Jacques* when speaking English really sounds discordant, as indeed would *Shackleton* (CHAC-LE-TON) if pronounced the English way when speaking French.

This is only my opinion, but the sounds and mouth movements of English and French are quite different. And if you try and conflate the two you end up with something that is less than poetic.

Comment: And then there's Spanish *Juan*, which is /wɑːn/ in San Juan, Texas, but /dʒuən/ in Byron's *Don Juan*.

Comment: Just to add another data point, in the US I've never heard "Jacques" pronounced "JAKES." In my experience it's generally pronounced "ZHOCK" and sometimes "JOCK." It would be jarring for me to hear someone called "JAKES" just because I've never heard that pronunciation for a first name under any spelling.

Comment: @LoreSjöberg I was talking here about the surname *Jacques*. A former colleague of mine, one Paul Jacques, introduced himself everywhere as Paul Jakes. I am aware of ZHOCK, as with various other American attempts at foreign words. But with respect, I think it neither replicates the French pronunciation, nor does it produce a sound which is recognisably English.

Comment: @WS2 Ah, missed that. I think the only person I know in the US with the last name Jacques pronounces it to rhyme with "stacks," but I have no idea if that's common.

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple. When speaking English, you speak *English*. The correct English pronunciation is the correct *English* pronunciation. And English doesn't so much as have all the sounds needed to pronounce words borrowed from French the French way. The French pronunciation is plain not *possible* in English. That's why the English pronunciation is different in the first place.

So if you think that using French pronunciation makes you sound pretentious, that's because it does. One major reason for that is because it is utterly random. Just ask yourself these three simple questions:

1. What is so special about French?
   Why do you want to pronounce *Paris* the way it's pronounced in French, but not *Los Angeles* the way it's prounounced in Spanish, *bistro* the way it's pronounced in Russian, or *kindergarten* the way it's pronounced in German? For that matter, are you even aware for every single word which language it comes from?
2. What is so special about that particular word?
   You don't pronounce *car* as [vwa.tyʁ], or *girl* as [ʒœn fij], so why do you want to pronounce *Paris* as [pa.ˈʁi]? It is just yet another pair of words for the same thing from different languages.
3. Why trace back the etymology exactly one step?
   Most of the words we got from French, French in turn got from Latin. So why stop at French? Why do you not want to use the Latin pronunciation? Or the Proto-Indo-European one?

To sum it up: You wouldn't use the English pronunciation of *Paris* when speaking French, except in very particular circumstances to drive home a specific point. Likewise, you don't use the French pronunciation of *Paris* when speaking English, except in very particular circumstances to drive home a specific point. If you don't have a point, then you just speak English. Like everyone else.

Comment: Hmm: is *bistro* pronounced the French, Russian or English way?

Comment: @Tim the kicker is that Russian borrowed *bistro* right back from French. Because in French it's a completely different word (even a different part of speech) from Russian. Needless to say, the Russian pronunciation of *bistro* is about as French as the French pronunciation of the original Russian *быстро*. And of course English can't mimic *any* of them. So between the three languages, you now have four pronunciations where there once was one. And that's just one word out of hundreds of thousands.

Comment: I think you missed the part where it was stated that the asker always pronounces _common_ place names (like Paris) according to their Anglicised pronunciation. The question is more about less common, and obviously French, words and names: what to do about _Alpe d’Huez_, _Cyrano de Bergerac_, _enjambement_, _je ne sais quoi_, etc. This is a dilemma faced by everyone speaking a non-native language.

Comment: @Janus: once again, there is nothing special about *Alpe d'Huez* as opposed to any other English word you've never articulated before. You just go ahead and take your best stab at it. Just like you did with *Worchestershire, Yosemite, Linux, hiccough, victuals, segue, colonel, ennui, sepulcher, viscount, biopic, epitome, queue, choir*, etc. Your best stab at it might very well be a pronunciation you know from another language, or an otherwise educated guess. And you will be well aware it's just your best stab and not necessarily the actual pronunciation you simply don't know at that point.

Comment: Your point about the French pronunciation not even being *possible* in English is important, and which many folks don’t realize. English and French aren’t in the same category in their **general *articulation***: you have to hold your mouth in a totally different way for one as for the other. English has a looser articulation than French (or IT or ES), but there are many other differences. To suddenly switch your particular “mouth-setting” (articulation) for a foreign word is jarring. [See here](http://blog.tahoeenglish.com/2010/01/23/its-all-in-your-mouth/) for a layman’s overview of this.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Sorry for the confusion. I wasn't considering English words of French origin, but words that don't have an established English pronunciation. I was at a conference this week on suicide prevention and the native French speaker used the French "accompagnant" (he who accompanies) instead of the English _counselor_, which he thought too cold. Would you use an anglicized pronunciation?

Comment: @TheThunderChimp that is a different situation entirely. That word does not *exist* in English, so of course you use the French pronunciation, because you're speaking French at that point. But frankly, it's completely up to you, because it's a neologism, and you are the one coining it. It's up for grabs and whatever you do is right. If it actually catches on, however, it absolutely *will* be adapted to the rules of English phonotactics, and you as the original author will have zero say in that.

Comment: @tchrist I think your remarks are particularly pertinent. Moreover the  point you make about the mouth applies equally to sudden changes on the ear of the listener. Nonetheless my own answer was applicable to French words which have an established English pronunciation. Where they don't the position is more difficult. I for one always pronounce *par excellence* the French way, whilst some will say 'par excellence' the English way. Ultimately I suppose the OP is right, in that it is what makes you feel comfortable which counts.

Comment: @Reg How is a word that doesn't exist in English a different matter from a word that you've never seen or uttered before? To the speaker, surely there is no practical difference. If I didn't know how to pronounce _Alpe d’Huez_ and tried pronouncing it according to English phonotactics and spelling, few would probably even understand what I was trying to say (‘alpie duh hews’?).